How do I convert an image that is a top view of a 3D model of a house into a 2D floor plan?
How do I convert an image, which is a top view of a 3D model of a house, into a 2D floor plan (e.g., an AutoCAD drawing)? What manual drawing techniques, mathematics, algorithms, and software are available?
The below example image is from an article entitled, "Inside All Creatures Great and Small’s Charming Period Production Design" by Masterpiece Theater.


good luck. you'll need some AI to recognize the walls, and everything else, because everything could be a wall, or not. the model has to understand everything it sees. -- way too broad a question. [ask], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]
